# GSI consumes WCU if it doesn't include updated attribute?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

#### Main table

```
{
  id: '123', // partition key
  name: 'John',
  age: 22, 
  isOnline: true // regularly changing
}
```

#### GSI

```
{
  age: '22', // partition key
  id: '123', // sort key
  name: 'John'
}
```

Trivial example, don't mind the architecture or possible bad key selection.

---

**My question is:**

If you don't project regularly changing attributes (`isOnline` in my example) to GSI and if I change these attributes on main table, does GSI still recieve updates and consume write capacity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only consume GSI WCUs if you update attributes that are part of the GSI. So in your case you can update `isOnline` for an item and this will consume **no** WCUs from your GSI.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html#GSI.ThroughputConsiderations

> When an item in a table is added, updated, or deleted, and a global
>   secondary index is affected by this, then the global secondary index
>   will consume provisioned write capacity units for the operation. The
>   total provisioned throughput cost for a write consists of the sum of
>   write capacity units consumed by writing to the base table and those
>   consumed by updating the global secondary indexes. **Note that if a
>   write to a table does not require a global secondary index update,
>   then no write capacity is consumed from the index.**